# PHP configure file in Linux

Tags: php

System: redhat

Configure:

```
./configure --prefix=/path/to/php/share/php --with-apxs2=/path/to/apache2/bin/apxs --with-mysql --with-libdir=lib64 --with-ldap --with-ldap-sasl --with-config-file-path=/path/to/php/share/php.ini
```

In php.ini i set **upload_max_filesize** to **50** and restart apache.

I use

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

to check. The configuration file (php.ini)path is correct but upload_max_filesize is still 2M.
Does anyone know why the configure failed? Thanks.

---

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
; http://php.net/upload-max-filesize
upload_max_filesize = 50M

; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
; http://php.net/date.timezone
date.timezone = Asia/Shanghai
```

Comment: No. In fact, I also set other parameters, eg date.timezone. All of them doesn't work.

Comment: I've listed some of the php.ini file.

Comment: I don't have access to my server, so I cannot check it now, but you can try to follow the directions in this [link](http://blog.jc21.com/2007-05-03/change-the-maximum-upload-size-with-php/) and see if solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks bacchus. The .htaccess works! But I still can't understand why the php.ini doesn't work.

Comment: As you have solved the question, you should post it as an answer for future visitors ;)

Comment: Concerning your other problem, [this](http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=475760) may help understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I don't have access to my server, so I cannot check it now, but you can try to follow the directions in this [link](http://blog.jc21.com/2007-05-03/change-the-maximum-upload-size-with-php/) and see if solves your problem. – bacchus**

Thanks bacchus. The .htaccess works! But I still can't understand why the php.ini doesn't work.

Comment: You should put the actual solution and the steps that you did to solve the problem and not my comment ;)

Answer (score 2):

Inside the information that phpinfo() shows the path to php.ini, double check that you are editing the right one, also after making the modifications you should restart apache :-).

Comment: Thanks. I've double checked all of these. I doubt the real work php.ini is not the one showed in phpinfo()

Comment: dumb question, have you tried to restart the webserver already?

Answer (score 0):

What does your phpinfo output look like exactly?
You might have to also increase the post_max_size setting.

Comment: I set all the three parameters:post_max_size,upload_max_filesize and memory_limit.